# How can I validate an MVC view model from a unit test?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5

I am writing unit tests to test an MVC application. How can I validate my view models from a unit test?

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually'?

Comment: I mean I need to force them to validate from a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Castle Validator you can use the following, the model can then be passed to the controller as usual.

```
var errors = CastleValidationRunner.Validate(model);

// Add each error to the ModelState.
foreach (var error in errors)
{
        var propertyName = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}.{1}", typeof(TModel).Name, error.PropertyName);
        modelState.AddModelError(propertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data annotations for validation you could [use reflection](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html) to test the presence of validation attributes. If you using [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) then it is a bit [more elegant](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation).